# Webservice returns "error", not sure if method is working

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I have `callWebservice()` method, and I need some web service to test it. I still learn about webservices generally, and this code is from tutorial. I am getting "error" as result, and I don't know what's wrong. Any tips, or some other services that i could use to test my code would be appriciated.

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/";
    private static final String METHODNAME = "AuthenticateTest";
    private static final String WSDL = "https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx?wsdl";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/AuthenticateTest";

    private static String TAG = "soap";

    public static String callWebservice() {

String res = "sample string";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHODNAME);
        request.addProperty("name","44vmMAYrhjf");
        request.addProperty("transactionKey","9MDQ7fghjghjh53H48k7e7n");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            res = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
return res;
    }
```

`AuthenticateTestResponse{AuthenticateTestResult=anyType{resultCode=Error; messages=anyType{MessagesTypeMessage=anyType{code=E00014; text=Merchant Authentication is required.; }; }; }; }`

Comment: where exactly you get `error`?

Comment: Inside response, but I'm not sure if values I put are wrong, or it's other problem, or maybe I'm missing something yet, I've edited my question.

Comment: `Merchant Authentication is required` is the error text. Which means that you need to double-check the documentation of API you are using

Comment: Ok, thanks, I just wasn't sure if it's code, or service. Now it seems it was service.